# How to auto populate multiple fields in attribute table?

Tags: python, arcmap, vba, field-calculator, attribute-table

i have Feature Class Buildings, it has many fields like this(Region_id,Region_Name,Governorate_Name,Village_id,Village_Name,Building_id,Building_Hight,Building_Area,Floor_No,Residential_Units_No_Commercial_Units_No,Administrative_Units_No_Other_Units_No)
my challenge is to reduce the time for populate values, i need when i finished create building polygon, then select it to auto populate parameters of attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [Associating default values and domains with tables and feature classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001s00000009000000).

It sounds like that is what you are after.

If not, perhaps you can expand the description of your Question and drop out a few of the field names because once you know how to do this for one or a few fields the rest should be easy.

Comment: thank you@PolyGeo i think it is good idea to work with Domains and Subtypes in this case study.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the fields [Region_id,Region_Name, Governorate_Name, Village_id, Village_Name] are based on the location of the building within other polygons. You could create a script to fill in these values based on the building coordinates.